# Add columns/properties to existing Entity Framework Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm building an application that will be exposed to the public. So the database will be filled with data. I'm not sure how to extend the model afterwards. Locally after any changes of the model the database get's recreated. How can add properties to the existing model, without recreate the entire database ?

Comment: So long as you abstract away the actual database entities with a business layer, changes to the underlying schema won't *necessarily* affect your models.

Comment: I like to change my models. It just don't want to recreate the entire database.

Comment: Why would changing your models cause the database to be recreated?  If you're using code-first then what you're likely referring to as `models` are what I'm referring to as `entities`.  You'll need to abstract it down another layer if you plan on making changes without causing entity framework to recreate your database every time.  Though, it sounds like you're a bit new to databases in general.  It might be worthwhile to read up on them before moving forward.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer, a thing I like to do is to add a meaningfull `ToString` to the generated classes (in database first)

Comment: Well now I'm confused.  Overriding the `ToString` method should't cause the database to be recreated; the schema wouldn't have changed as a result of that addition.

Comment: @JoshuaShearer: It seems I answered another question :)

Comment: @JoshuaShearer I've made everything very abstract and i've 3 layers. You need to be more specific about this point. I like to change my model first to generate a extra column into the database. Model no (s).

Comment: If you add a property to your entities (database models) then entity framework will recreate your database.  If you want to avoid that, look at this particular question for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389585/update-database-schema-on-model-change-without-data-loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at EntityFramework CodeFirst Migration, for modifying your schema.

[MSDN Link for Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj591621.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe there is a better solution. Waiting. If not accept.

Comment: I'm not sure how OP intends to maintain his data in an RDBMS if he keeps changing the definition of his data.  Migrations are pretty much the *only* way to go.  OP and NoSQL sound like a match made in heaven.